# Javascript out of memory

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code was extracted and condensed from the larger code base. It just exists to nail down my issue.

```
function testit(N) {
    var result = [];
    var row    = [];
    var field  = '';

    function flushField() {
        row.push(field);
        field = '';
    }

    function flushRow() {
        result.push(row);
        row = [];
    }

    for (var row_count=0; row_count<N; ++row_count) {
        for (var field_count=0; field_count<10; ++field_count) {
            field = row_count + ' ' + field_count;
            flushField();
        }
        flushRow();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It results in an out of memory for N=47000 at the statement `row = [];`. The same code does not result in an out of memory for N=46000. If I compute the numbers each row is an array of 10 elements "fields". Each field is a string of less than 10 characters. So overall there will be less than 4 700 0000 chracters in 47 000 row arrays that contain 470 000 field arrays. Overall something that I would expect this to consume some mega bytes. However my machine has several giga bytes.

Why does this result in an out of memory?

Comment: try doing using Web woker https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: well one thing id recommend is running this code on google chrome, hitting shift+escape to open chrome task manager and checking how much memory this actually consumes

Comment: @UdoKlein: Don't you get stop running slow scripts exception?

Comment: @UdoKlein why do you need to keep `47.001` arrays and `470.000` strings in memory? Even if you can optimize this code you can still find an `N` that is too large.

Comment: As I said this is part of a larger code base. Before I even attempt to refactor it I will have to understand the underlying issue. Of course I can replace the "flush" by a function call. Then this function can process the items. This will decrease memory consumption of this part of the code. But later on the stuff is collected again in a similar fashion. If I want to get rid of this I need to refactor an extensive code base that contains stuff that was implemented by other people. Before I even attempt to mess with this stuff I would prefer to understand what is going on.

Comment: As suggested I did some testing with Chrome --> N=400 000 is still OK and consumes the expected amount of memory. Firefox will also cope with N=400 000. Obviously not all javascript engines are created equal. Unfortunately I have no choice here :(  Of course this changes the nature of the question somewhat.